# How to determine the error type from MySQL

Tags: mysql, go, error-handling

I'm really confused how to get the error type from a failed query line with the MySQL import. There is no real documentation on it, so it has me real confused.

I have:

```
result, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)", username, hashedPassword, email)
if err != nil {
    // handle different types of errors here
    return
}
```

I could print err but its just a string, not liking the idea of peeking at strings to know what went wrong, is there no feedback to get an error code to perform a `switch` on or something along those lines? How do you do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, checking the content of the error string is a bad practice,  the string value might vary depending on the driver verison. It’s much better and robust to compare error numbers to identify what a specific error is.

There are the error codes for the **mysql** driver, the [package](https://github.com/VividCortex/mysqlerr) is maintained separately from the main driver package. The mechanism to do this varies between drivers, however, because this isn’t part of database/sql itself. With that package you can check the type of error [`MySQLError`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/a8b7ed4454a6a4f98f85d3ad558cd6d97cec6959/errors.go#L58):

```
if driverErr, ok := err.(*mysql.MySQLError); ok {
    if driverErr.Number == mysqlerr.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR {
        // Handle the permission-denied error
    }
}
```

There are also error [`variables`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/a8b7ed4454a6a4f98f85d3ad558cd6d97cec6959/errors.go#L19).

<sub>[Ref](http://go-database-sql.org/errors.html)</sub>

Comment: Can you explain whats going on with the first line i have never seen syntax like that.. Is it a cast from `error` to `mysql.MySQLError` ? Or is that a function call.. a bit confusing.

Comment: It's an error type casting, it's just an example how to fetch error and compare with number from external package.

Answer (score 3):

normally in packages you could see Variables if the package author want to separate errors make variable for each of them like :
https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#pkg-variables

you could see errors and you could switch the error in return and case each error variable.

example:

```
result, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES (?,?,?)", username, hashedPassword, email)
if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
    // handle error
    return
}
if err == sql.ErrTxDone {
    // handle error
    return
}
```

Comment: Better option is a switch on error, rather than successive If statements: https://play.golang.org/p/-d_skg2tK-